# How can I generate a full timeseries from only a single input using a recurrent neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I wanted to know how I should configure a recurrent neural network to produce a timeseries from inputs which are only single instances of a feature.

For example, let's suppose that the timeseries used to train this network is a sinusoid and the input variables (features) are it amplitude and frequency. Since this isn't a sequence to sequence model it isn't possible to give the recurrent neural network inputs at every time point. Is there some configuration of a recurrent neural network that would work for this problem?

Comment: I guess you need to feed back your state (current output) in order to generate the output. Using this as input, you can generate test data that will look like "sequence to sequence" can't you?

Comment: I was thinking that something like this might work where the output of the network at the previous layer can be fed in as input to the next layer. Is it possible to implement this on Keras?